# JavaScript - need help combining two scripts.

Tags: javascript, html

I’m trying to call a user input array.

I’m very new on Javascript but know I somehow need to reference the array (it is somewhere where I put the ???).

```
<script> 
var arrayX =5; 
var arrayY =1; 
var array=new Array(arrayX); 
var planetIndex=0; 

for (x=0; x<array.length; x++) 
{array [x] = new Array(arrayY);} 

function insert(val1){ 
    array[planetIndex][0]=val1; 
    planetIndex++; 
    document.getElementById('name').value = ''; };

function worldChange() {
        var newplanet = ????????????
        var whichWorld = Math.floor(Math.random()*newplanet.length); 
        return planetIndex[whichWorld];

        var planets = document.getElementsByClassName("world-name")
              for (var i=0; i < planets.length; i++) {
                planets[i].innerHTML = worldChange();};
        };

</script>
<body> 
   <div>  
    <form> 
              <input type="integer" id="name"/>
            <input type="button" value="Add Planets" onclick="insert   (this.form.name.value);"/> 
        </form>

        <input type="button" value="See planet!" onClick="worldChange()" />
        <br> Hello <span class="world-name">Earth!</span><br /> 
</div>
</body>
```

I got both elements of the script to work perfectly on my site so every time someone hits a button it changes the guy in the story. But as you see if pulls from the array I created. I want to pull from an array that a user creates so they could input their own list of names.

so this script works fine:

```
function newGuy() {
        var guys = new Array ("Jeff", "Mike", "George", "Harold");
        var whichGuy = Math.floor(Math.random()*guys.length); 
        return guys[whichGuy];}

var guy = document.getElementsByClassName("guy")
     for (var i=0; i < guy.length; i++) {
        guy[i].innerHTML = newGuy();}
```

And this script works alone:

```
var arrayX =5; 
var arrayY =1; 
var array=new Array(arrayX); 
var guyIndex=0; 

for (x=0; x<array.length; x++) 
{array [x] = new Array(arrayY);} 

function insert(val1){ 
    array[guyIndex][0]=val1; 
    guyIndex++; 
    document.getElementById('name').value = ''; };
```

Just baffled on how to put them together.

Comment: I see this is related to your previous question(s). Just an advice: You cannot build your application step by step by asking questions on Stack Overflow. You won't get anywhere and such questions are of no use to anyone else (too specific to your situation). You have to learn the basics through tutorials/books/etc.

Comment: Also, try using comments and meaningful variable names. What is arrayX/arrayY?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of problems with your script but to give you an idea on how to get it to work :

```
var planets = [];
// define how many planets there will be initially
var initialLength = 5;

// add the initital planets
for (x = 0; x < initialLength; x++) {
    planets.push("planet" + x);
}

function insert() {
        var planetToInsert = document.getElementById('name').value;
    if (planetToInsert) {
        // add the input to the array of planets
        planets.push(planetToInsert);
        document.getElementById('name').value = '';
    } else {
        alert("please enter a value");
    }
}


function worldChange() {
    // randomly pick an index
    var whichWorld = Math.floor(Math.random() * planets.length);
    document.getElementById('world-name').innerHTML = planets[whichWorld];
}
```

working sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jJFYw/)

For finding problems in you code jsFiddle can be of excellent help. Run JSlint to find the basic errors, put in alerts as poor mans debugging.

For a good javascript book I would recommend [javascript patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596806767.do)